# R converting latitude and longitude point and shapefiles for ppp objects

Tags: r

I am trying to use the ppp function for spatial point data in R. I understand that one needs euclidean distances for this rather than latitude and longitude. I am wondering how to take my point data and shapefile for the area and convert them into something useable for the ppp object.

So I used the code below for the point data and have something that looks like it might be reasonable. I am somewhat unfamiliar with the CRS projections and am not sure that I correctly defined things. For instance I can just define the proj4string as longlat or do the conversion WGS84.

```
LatLong<-ASA[,304:305]

#Not sure if this actually is doing what I think I am doing (converting from lat/long to a format with euclidean distance):

id.spp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = LatLong, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), data = ASA)

#I also tried just using the input as lat long without any second part. both give workable output, but not sure if they are correct
id.spp2 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = LatLong, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat "), data = ASA)

#I then converted both versions using the code below:
ppp<-as(as(id.spp, "SpatialPoints"), "ppp")

plot(ppp)

plot(StudyArea_GCS, add=T)

#Appears to reasonably surround points in anticipated way even though i did not do any type of conversion - it is in lat/long. 

#The lat/long points, appear to be in the same place as the ppp points. 
points(LatLong,pch=".")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please make a minimal effort and try something and then post some code. This is really too little to go on.

Comment: Good job , but now you need to edit your original question and copy the code into it. It is quite easy really

Comment: Will have a closer look when I am back from a walk

Comment: Okay, had a look, and there is still not enough there to be clear of your intentions. Can you post some ASA data? And maybe a more complete program fragment?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I can't actually share the data itself due to data research protections but it is a large dataset each row relating to a person who was tested for disease from a randomly selected subset of people in a 170 square kilometer area. There are a large number of columns describing various lab data, household, and individual information about the people tested. columns 304 and 305 are longitude and latitude of the household where the individual lives. I plan to use the positives and negatives and do a case-control kind of analysis looking for temporal spatial relationships in disease.

Comment: This gives a good answer to this https://rpubs.com/Seth/Exp_Point_Pattern